# Flask form redirects to same page

Tags: python, html, flask

My webapp has two pages: `home` and `maps`. Clicking on either button on `home` should redirect to `maps` (with different parameters). However, on clicking Flask routes me to `'/'` (home). I tried getting around this with a redirect, but then the form data wasn't preserved.

Here is the relevant code: `home.html`

```
    <form method="POST" href="/maps">
    <div class="next_btns">
            <button class="hidden_btns searchBtn btn-primary" type="submit" name="spot" id="spot_btn">Spot</button>
            <button class="hidden_btns searchBtn btn-primary" type="submit" name="event" id="events_btn">Events</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

`app.py`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home_page():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/maps', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def maps():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('404.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if 'spot' in request.form:
            return render_template('maps.html', filter='spot')
        elif 'event' in request.form:
            return render_template('maps.html', filter='event')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your form to use `action` instead of `href`.

```
<form method="POST" action="/maps">
  <div class="next_btns">
    <button class="hidden_btns searchBtn btn-primary" type="submit" name="spot" id="spot_btn">Spot</button>
    <button class="hidden_btns searchBtn btn-primary" type="submit" name="event" id="events_btn">Events</button>
  </div>
</form>
```